# Magento SOAP v2 API Error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, magento, soap

I'm getting the error, in visual studio 2013 c#

MAPI Error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'

My WSDL file 
have annotation

> import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />

Any method to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just encountered the same error. Testing from different systems, it appears that the xmlsoap.org site is erratically unavailable:

```
$ GET http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
Can't connect to schemas.xmlsoap.org:80 (Connection timed out)
```

So your best bet is to cache it locally.

I also wrote a blog post about [the worldwide crash of Magento API's](https://www.byte.nl/blog/caused-worldwide-crash-magento-apis-yesterday/).